# Why do I have error with multi long options using getopt in bash?

Tags: bash, getopt

I just wrote a script in bash, which work expect for multi long option:

```
    #!/bin/bash
OPTS=`getopt -q -o fdhl: -l free,df,help,log:  -- "$*"`
#Check if error with getopt
if [ $? != 0 ]
then
        echo -e  "error: parameter could not be found\n\nUsage:\n supervision [options]\n\n Try 'supervision --help'\n  or 'supervision -h'\n for additional help text." ;      
    exit 1
fi
eval set -- "$OPTS"
while true ; do
    case "$1" in
        -f|--free)
            free -h ; 
            shift;; 
        -d|--df)
            df -h ;  #Run df system command
            shift;;
        -l|--log)
            case "$2" in 
                "") echo "miss file" ;
                        shift 2;; #No file passed as parameter
                *)  
                df -h >> "$2" ;
                 shift 2;;
            esac ;;
        -h|--help) #Display help
               shift;;
        --) #End of parsed parameters list
            shift ; break ;;
        *)
            break   ;;
    esac
done
```

I don't get why i'm supposed to, when I use more than 1 long option, for example:

```
sh myscript --free --df
```

And when I use --log:

```
sh myscript --log logfile
```

Both case exit on the if [ $? != 0 ], seems like the element which follow the 1st long option doesn't get parsed.

Comment: You have to describe the errors you get, and reduce the script to the shortest possible version that still produces that error. Chances are that you find the problem while reducing the script. See also [mcve].

Comment: In addition to Benjamin's suggestion it would help to post output if it is relevant.

Comment: thanks for your response, just edit and shorten code and add example input/ouput.

Comment: add an `echo "OPTS=$OPTS"` to confirm the arguments are being parsed as  you expect. Good luck.

Comment: hi shelter, i did it: when write sh myscript --free I got OPTS= --free -- '-'
Which is normal. However when i write: sh myscript --free --df  I got OPTS= -- '-' Which is very strange, same for --log. 
I can't understand why getopt did it.

Comment: There is definitely an error executing `getopt` command. Are there any messages sent to sdterr?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I figured out and it's all due to the using of "$*" instead of "$@" in the getopt call. I don't exactly why, i guessed both do the same thing, but it turns out to be the one which causes the problem.

Comment: Check your manual page for clarification. Mine clearly states to use `$*` and not `$@`: "you should not use `getopt abo: "$@"` since that would parse the arguments differently from what the set command below does"